# Errors occur when moving the same code to \AtBeginDocument and \AtEndDocument

Tags: tables

My objective is to create a table with the following properties.

- For even number of items:

  [image]
- For odd number of items:

  [image]

The minimal working example is given as follows.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{longtable,array}
\newcounter{counter}

\makeatletter
\newcolumntype\specifier{%
    |
    *2{>{\centering\stepcounter{counter}\thecounter}m{1cm}
        |>{\centering}m{0.5\dimexpr\linewidth-2cm-8\tabcolsep-5\arrayrulewidth\relax}
        |}
}


\def\row[#1]#2{%
        & \parbox[c][0.2\dimexpr\textheight-6\arrayrulewidth-\topskip\relax][c]{\linewidth}{\centering #1 \par \vspace{15pt} #2}
        \ifodd\value{counter}
            \expandafter\@firstoftwo
        \else
            \expandafter\@secondoftwo
        \fi
        {&}{\tabularnewline\hline}
}

\let\oldendlongtable\endlongtable
\def\endlongtable{%
\ifodd\value{counter}\omit\tabularnewline\cline{1-2}\fi
\oldendlongtable}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{empty}


% option 1
%\AtBeginDocument{\topskip=0pt\relax\begin{longtable}{\specifier}\hline}
%\AtEndDocument{\end{longtable}}

\begin{document}

% option 2
\topskip=0pt\relax
\begin{longtable}{\specifier}\hline

\row[A]{B}
\row[C]{D}
\row[E]{F}

% option 2
\end{longtable}


\end{document}
```

## Problems

For a reason that I don't want to explain too much here, I want to move both

```
% option 2
\topskip=0pt\relax
\begin{longtable}{\specifier}\hline
```

and

```
% option 2
\end{longtable}
```

to

```
% option 1
\AtBeginDocument{\topskip=0pt\relax\begin{longtable}{\specifier}\hline}
\AtEndDocument{\end{longtable}}
```

In other words, I want to disable option 2 and enable option 1. If I do that, I get two kind of errors:

- For even numbers of items, the code is totally uncompilable.
- For odd numbers of items, the code is compilable but the output is wrong.

In order to keep this question simple, please make a try by yourself. So, how to solve it?

### Notes:

- The input file above is specially used only to create a table so the body only contains macros for rows. No other typesetting macros is allowed for sure.
- I don't want to redefine `\document` because I have a large number of input files using my package that defines codes sandwiched between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` as shown above.

Comment: You are trying to wrap the whole document body into a `longtable`? `\AtBeginDocument` mustn't contain code which is meant for typesetting, since it is actually executed before `document` starts (at least parts of it)

Comment: I hope my question is sexy enough.

Comment: I am working on it, but actually, I don't recommend this wrapping at all

Comment: There is no choice. I have to do it. But I will not explain why I have to do this way as I don't want to make the communication long. :-)

Comment: The actual trouble comes from the `\ifodd` statement

Comment: Ok, I don't need to answer it, there is already an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a `longtabledocument` environment.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{longtable,array}
\newcounter{counter}

\makeatletter
\newcolumntype\specifier{%
    |
    *2{>{\centering\stepcounter{counter}\thecounter}m{1cm}
        |>{\centering}m{0.5\dimexpr\linewidth-2cm-8\tabcolsep-5\arrayrulewidth\relax}
        |}
}


\def\row[#1]#2{%
        & \parbox[c][0.2\dimexpr\textheight-6\arrayrulewidth-\topskip\relax][c]{\linewidth}{\centering #1 \par \vspace{15pt} #2}
        \ifodd\value{counter}
            \expandafter\@firstoftwo
        \else
            \expandafter\@secondoftwo
        \fi
        {&}{\tabularnewline\hline}
}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{empty}


\newenvironment{longtabledocument}
 {\document
  \topskip=0pt
  \begin{longtable}{\specifier}\hline}
 {\ifodd\value{counter}\omit\tabularnewline\cline{1-2}\fi
  \end{longtable}\enddocument}

\begin{longtabledocument}

\row[A]{B}
\row[C]{D}
\row[E]{F}

\end{longtabledocument}
```

Alternative, with `etoolbox`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{longtable,array,etoolbox}
\newcounter{counter}

\makeatletter
\newcolumntype\specifier{%
    |
    *2{>{\centering\stepcounter{counter}\thecounter}m{1cm}
        |>{\centering}m{0.5\dimexpr\linewidth-2cm-8\tabcolsep-5\arrayrulewidth\relax}
        |}
}


\def\row[#1]#2{%
        & \parbox[c][0.2\dimexpr\textheight-6\arrayrulewidth-\topskip\relax][c]{\linewidth}{\centering #1 \par \vspace{15pt} #2}
        \ifodd\value{counter}
            \expandafter\@firstoftwo
        \else
            \expandafter\@secondoftwo
        \fi
        {&}{\tabularnewline\hline}
}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{empty}

\topskip=0pt

\AfterEndPreamble{%
  \begin{longtable}{\specifier}\hline
}
\preto\enddocument{\ifodd\value{counter}\omit\tabularnewline\cline{1-2}\fi\end{longtable}}

\begin{document}

\row[A]{B}
\row[C]{D}
\row[E]{F}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you keep solving it without defining a new document? If you do this way, it will break my existing complicate scenario. :-)

Comment: @FriendlyGhost Perhaps redefining `\document` and `\enddocument`; but why?

Comment: I don't want to touch `\document`.

Comment: @FriendlyGhost I don't understand the requirements, but here you have what you're looking for.